Move SQL data from one table to another with preserving foreign keys in third
I want to move data from several similarly structured tables like old_metadata to table new_metadata and update references in tables respectively. For example deposit has field metadata_id that references old_metadata.id. Trick is I don't know id's of records in new_metadata tables until they are created;
Table structures are like:
old_metadata

id | amount
---+-------
0  | 30
1  | 40

new_metadata

id | amount | metadata_type
---+--------+--------------
31 | 30     | OLD_METADATA
32 | 40     | OLD_METADATA

deposits

id | metadata_id | ...
---+-------------+----
11 | 1           |
12 | 2           |

So what i've tried was
ALTER TABLE deposits ADD COLUMN new_metadata_id INT REFERENCES new_metadata(id);

WITH metadata AS (
    INSERT INTO new_metadata (amount, metadata_type)
        SELECT amount, 'OLD_METADATA' FROM old_metadata
        RETURNING id, old_metadata.id as old_id
) 
UPDATE deposits SET new_metadata_id = metadata.id
FROM metada
WHERE metadata_id = metadata.old_id;

My next steps would be replace data in old column with new but it fails saying missing FROM-clause entry for table "old_metadata".
Alternatively may be it can be done with cursors or temp tables but I believe it's not the most straightforward way.
Sloppy but working solution would be something like
ALTER TABLE new_metadata ADD COLUMN old_id INT;
ALTER TABLE deposits ADD COLUMN new_metadata_id INT;

WITH metadata AS (
    INSERT INTO new_metadata (amount, metadata_type, old_id)
        SELECT amount, 'OLD_METADATA', id FROM old_metadata
        RETURNING *
)
UPDATE deposits SET new_metadata_id = metadata.id
FROM new_metadata, old_metadata
WHERE metadata_id = new_metadata.old_id;

UPDATE deposits SET metadata_id = deposits.new_metadata_id

ALTER TABLE deposits DROP COLUMN new_metadata_id
ALTER TABLE new_metadata DROP COLUMN old_id


Combine your multiple-table data into one plain table. Then insert this data onto new places saving the references.

Removed mysql tag, this problem is clearly using PostgreSQL, because MySQL doesn't support INSERT...RETURNING syntax.

@BillKarwin but i would be totally ok with pure sql solution

Why not?: ALTER TABLE old_meta ADD COLUMN  metadata_type varchar

I want to merge several old tables with exact structure in to one, so even if I edit old_metadata there are like 10 similar another_old_metadata tables with exact same problem.

This is information that should be in the question as it changes the nature of the answer.

See example
Data model for test:
create table old_metadata ( id int primary key generated by default as identity, amount int);
insert into old_metadata values
 (0, 30)
,(1, 40)
,(2, 50)
;
create table new_metadata ( id int primary key generated by default as identity
  , amount int,metadata_type varchar(20));
insert into new_metadata values
 (31 , 30,    'OLD_METADATA')
,(32 , 40,    'OLD_METADATA')
;
create table deposits ( id int primary key generated by default as identity
  , metadata_id int );
alter table deposits add constraint 
    cx_reference_fk_old_metadata FOREIGN KEY (metadata_id) references old_metadata;
insert into deposits values
 (11 , 1)
,(12 , 2)
;

CREATE TABLE, INSERT 0 3, CREATE TABLE, INSERT 0 2, CREATE TABLE, ALTER TABLE, INSERT 0 2
old_metadata



id
amount




0
30


1
40


2
50



new_metadata



id
amount
metadata_type




31
30
OLD_METADATA


32
40
OLD_METADATA



deposits



id
metadata_id




11
1


12
2



Add column old_metadata_id to table new_metadata. This column can be deleted later.
ALTER TABLE new_metadata ADD COLUMN old_metadata_id INT REFERENCES old_metadata(id);

We will insert into new_metadata values from old_metadata with new Id.
For simplicity, let's make sure that the next Id does not overlap with those already present in new_metadata. We set next Id to max(id)+1=32+1=33.
SELECT setval('new_metadata_id_seq', max(id)) FROM new_metadata;




setval




32



Drop reference to old_metadata.
ALTER TABLE deposits DROP CONSTRAINT cx_reference_fk_old_metadata;

WITH metadata AS (
    INSERT INTO new_metadata (amount, metadata_type,old_metadata_id)
        SELECT amount, 'OLD_METADATA' metadata_type,id as old_metadata_id FROM old_metadata
        RETURNING id, old_metadata_id 
) 
UPDATE deposits SET metadata_id = metadata.id
FROM metadata
WHERE metadata_id = old_metadata_id;


UPDATE 2


Set reference to new_metadata
alter table deposits add constraint 
    cx_reference_fk_new_metadata FOREIGN KEY (metadata_id) references new_metadata;

After UPDATE
old_metadata



id
amount




0
30


1
40


2
50



new_metadata



id
amount
metadata_type
old_metadata_id




31
30
OLD_METADATA
null


32
40
OLD_METADATA
null


33
30
OLD_METADATA
0


34
40
OLD_METADATA
1


35
50
OLD_METADATA
2



deposits



id
metadata_id




11
34


12
35



fiddle
For question can this part cause collision when newely set metadata_id has the id that is in old_metadata_id variables?
UPDATE deposits SET metadata_id = metadata.id FROM metadata WHERE metadata_id = old_metadata_id;

If you have one old_metadata table, then the intersection of new_metadata_id and old_metadata_id does not cause problems.
If you have several old_metadata tables, then this problem may arise if you consistently process these tables in the specified way.
In this case, it is better to collect all old_metadata in one table and then apply the update 1 time.
Or calculate max(old_metadata_id) in all old_metadata tables and set this value as nextval for new_metadata_id. In this case new_metadata_id will be greater than all old_metadata_id.
If you have intersections by old_metadata_id in the old_metadata tables, then you first need to resolve this collision in some way. This is no longer relevant to your question.
SELECT * FROM pg_sequences WHERE sequencename LIKE '%id%';




schemaname
sequencename
sequenceowner
data_type
start_value
min_value
max_value
increment_by
cycle
cache_size
last_value




public
old_metadata_id_seq
postgres
integer
1
1
2147483647
1
f
1
null


public
new_metadata_id_seq
postgres
integer
1
1
2147483647
1
f
1
35


public
deposits_id_seq
postgres
integer
1
1
2147483647
1
f
1
null




UPDATE deposits SET metadata_id = metadata.id FROM metadata WHERE metadata_id = old_metadata_id; can this part cause collision when newely set metadata_id has the id that is in old_metadata_id variables?
